# c sharp: Adobe PDF DLL for IJSMessageHandler Interface

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, adobe

Task: c sharp code calling acrobat sdk.  How to capture return messages using JSObject and IJSMessageHandler interface. Downloaded but not correct Acrobat_DC_SDK_Windows_2021_v3 using Interop.Acrobal.dll.  What is the link to download the correct Abode DLL ?

```
MyJSMessageHandler: IJSMessageHandler // Link to Adobe DLL?
{
    public void OnMessage( string msg )
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}

AcroPDDoc pdfDoc = new AcroPDDoc();
pdfDoc.Open("sourcPDF.pdf");
Object jsObj = pdfDoc.GetJSObject();            

jsObj.MessageHandler = handler;   // Capture return messages

type = jsObj.GetType();
object[] saveAsParam = { "targetWord.docx", "com.adobe.acrobat.docx" };
type.InvokeMember(
    "saveAs",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
    BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.Instance,
    null, jsObj, saveAsParam);
```

Thanks for help.